# Same code works/gives error in different projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I am using visual studio 2019.

When I try to run this from a new project it works totally fine. Sends the email and doesn't give any error.

But when I try to run this from my server code it gives this error:

To be more precise:

Project1/DEBUG  works fine.

Project1/Release works fine.

Project2/DEBUG works fine.

Project2/Release gives runtime error.

> "Exception thrown: read access violation.
>   **this** was 0xF. occurred"

And compiler is redirected to "xstring" code page, line 2873.

**part from xstring**

```
basic_string& assign(_In_reads_(_Count) const _Elem* const _Ptr, _CRT_GUARDOVERFLOW const size_type _Count) {
        // assign [_Ptr, _Ptr + _Count)
        if (_Count <= _Mypair._Myval2._Myres) {  // LINE 2873
            _Elem* const _Old_ptr   = _Mypair._Myval2._Myptr();
            _Mypair._Myval2._Mysize = _Count;
            _Traits::move(_Old_ptr, _Ptr, _Count);
            _Traits::assign(_Old_ptr[_Count], _Elem());
            return *this;
        }
```

I've tried with totally same code (with copy paste) but still no use. 
Project properties are the same. I've checked it several times for any change in properties but there is not even a single difference.

**email.h**

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996) //_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#ifndef EMAIL_H
#define EMAIL_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "curl/curl.h"

// Enable one of the below depending on your operating system
#define WINDOWS_H
//#define LINUX_H

class Email
{
public:
    // default constructor
    Email();

    // sets who the email is going to
    void setTo(const std::string to);

    // sets who the email came from
    void setFrom(const std::string from);

    // sets the cc
    void setCc(const std::string to);

    // sets the subject of the email
    void setSubject(const std::string subject);

    // set the body of the email
    void setBody(const std::string body);

    // sets the smtp username 
    void setSMTP_username(const std::string username);

    // sets the smtp password 
    void setSMTP_password(const std::string password);

    // sets the SMTP HOST
    void setSMTP_host(const std::string host);

    // adds a binary attachment to the email
    void addAttachment(const std::string filepath);

    // removes an attachment from the email (Not implemented yet)
    void removeAttachment(const std::string filepath);

    // removes all attachments
    void removeAllAttachments();

    // contructs the final email
    void constructEmail();

    // clears the contents of the email
    void clearEmailContents();

    // void send email
    int send() const; // returns a CURL error code

    // dumps the email contents for debugging
    void dump() const;

private:
    // smtp information
    std::string smtp_user;
    std::string smtp_password;
    std::string smtp_host;

    // email data
    std::string to;
    std::string from;
    std::string cc;
    std::string subject;
    std::string body;

    // vector which stores the email data
    std::vector<std::string> email_contents;
    std::vector<std::string> attachments;

    // length of the above vector
    int numberOfLines;
};

#endif
```

**email.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string.h>

// #include "stdafx.h"
#include "email.h"

#define MAX_LEN 255 // this must be divisible by 3 otherwise the SMTP server won't be able to decode the attachment properly
#define ENCODED_LEN 341

// offsets into the email template 
#define BOUNDARY 5
#define END_LINE 8
#define ATTACH_TYPE 10
#define ATTACH_TRANSFER 11
#define ATTACH_DEPOSITION 12
#define END_OF_TRANSMISSION_BOUNDARY 15
#define END_OF_TRANSMISSION 16

#ifdef WINDOWS_H
#define DIR_CHAR '\\'
#else
#define DIR_CHAR '/'
#endif

using namespace std;

// base64 encoding functions
void base64_encode(char* input_buf, char* output_buf, size_t input_size);
void encodeblock(char* in, char* out, int len);

// callback function
static size_t payload_source(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp);

// base64 encoding table
const char b64_table[65] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

// global vector this is TEMP
vector<string> global_vec;

// struct used by the CURL callback
struct upload_status {
    int lines_read;
};

static const char* email_template[] = {
    /* i = 0 */
    "User-Agent: DXF Viewer agent\r\n",
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n",
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n",
    " boundary=\"------------030203080101020302070708\"\r\n",
    "\r\nThis is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n",
    "--------------030203080101020302070708\r\n", // use this type of boundary for subsequent attachments
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed\r\n",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n",
    /* i = 8 (BODY) */
    "\r\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */
    "--------------030203080101020302070708\r\n", /* i = 9 */
    /* Template for binary attachments i = 10 */
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n",
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n",
    /* Filename here */
    "\r\n",
    /* Encoded base64 contents here */
    "\r\n",
    "--------------030203080101020302070708--\r\n", // this type of boundary indicates that there are no more parts i = 15
    "\r\n.\r\n",
    NULL
};

Email::Email()
{
    // empty constructor
}

void Email::setTo(const string to)
{
    this->to = to;
}

void Email::setFrom(const string from)
{
    this->from = from;
}

void Email::setCc(const string cc)
{
    this->cc = cc;
}

void Email::setSubject(const string subject)
{
    this->subject = subject;
}

void Email::setBody(const string body)
{
    this->body = body;
}

void Email::setSMTP_username(const string user)
{
    this->smtp_user = user;
}

void Email::setSMTP_password(const string pass)
{
    this->smtp_password = pass;
}

void Email::setSMTP_host(const string hostname)
{
    this->smtp_host = hostname;
}

void Email::addAttachment(const string file_path)
{
    /*FILE* fp = NULL;
    char buffer[MAX_LEN + 1] = { 0 };
    char encodedBuffer[ENCODED_LEN] = { 0 };
    char tempBuffer[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
    char* filename = NULL;
    unsigned int fileSize = 0;
    unsigned int bytesCopied = 0;
    int bytesToCopy = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0;

    fp = fopen(file_path.c_str(), "rb");
    if (fp) {
        // get the file size
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        fileSize = ftell(fp);
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

        // copy the attachment header
        string type(email_template[ATTACH_TYPE]);
        this->attachments.push_back(type);

        string encodingType(email_template[ATTACH_TRANSFER]);
        this->attachments.push_back(encodingType);

        string deposition(email_template[ATTACH_DEPOSITION]);
        this->attachments.push_back(deposition);

        // extract the filename from the path
        filename = (char*)strrchr(file_path.c_str(), DIR_CHAR);

        if (filename != NULL) {
            filename += 1;
            // push the filename
            snprintf(tempBuffer, MAX_LEN, "  filename=\"%s\"\r\n", filename);

            string filename(tempBuffer);
            this->attachments.push_back(filename);

            string endLine(email_template[END_LINE]);
            this->attachments.push_back(endLine);

            // copy the file MAX_LEN bytes at a time into the attachments vector
            while (bytesCopied < fileSize) {
                // determine how many bytes to read
                if (bytesCopied + MAX_LEN > fileSize) {
                    bytesToCopy = fileSize - bytesCopied;
                }

                else {
                    bytesToCopy = MAX_LEN;
                }

                // read from the file
                memset(buffer, 0, MAX_LEN + 1);
                bytesRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), bytesToCopy, fp);

                // encoded the data read
                memset(encodedBuffer, 0, ENCODED_LEN);
                base64_encode(buffer, encodedBuffer, bytesRead);

                // setup the encoded string so that we can push it to attachments
                string line(encodedBuffer);
                line += endLine;

                this->attachments.push_back(line);

                // update the number of bytes we have copied
                bytesCopied += bytesToCopy;
            }

            this->attachments.push_back(endLine);

            string boundary(email_template[BOUNDARY]);
            this->attachments.push_back(boundary);

        }

        else {
            removeAllAttachments();
            cout << "Failed to extract filename!" << endl;
        }


        // close the file
        fclose(fp);
    }

    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file." << endl;
    }
    */
}

void Email::constructEmail(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    char buffer[MAX_LEN];
    string boundary(email_template[BOUNDARY]);

    // time stuff
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm* timeinfo;

    // store all the email contents in a vector
    // TO:
    snprintf(buffer, MAX_LEN, "To: %s\r\n", this->to.c_str());
    string line1(buffer);
    this->email_contents.push_back(line1);

    // FROM:
    memset(buffer, 0, MAX_LEN);
    snprintf(buffer, MAX_LEN, "From: %s\r\n", this->from.c_str());
    string line2(buffer);
    this->email_contents.push_back(line2);

    // CC:
    memset(buffer, 0, MAX_LEN);
    snprintf(buffer, MAX_LEN, "Cc: %s\r\n", this->cc.c_str());
    string line3(buffer);

    if (this->cc.length() > 0) {
        this->email_contents.push_back(line3);
    }

    // Subject:
    memset(buffer, 0, MAX_LEN);
    snprintf(buffer, MAX_LEN, "Subject: %s\r\n", this->subject.c_str());
    string line4(buffer);
    this->email_contents.push_back(line4);

    // time:
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    memset(buffer, 0, MAX_LEN);
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S +1100\r\n", timeinfo);
    string time_str(buffer);

    this->email_contents.push_back(time_str);

    cout << time_str << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < END_LINE; i++) { // other stuff e.g user-agent etc
        string line(email_template[i]);
        this->email_contents.push_back(line);
    }

    // add in the body
    string endLine(email_template[END_LINE]);
    this->email_contents.push_back(endLine);

    memset(buffer, 0, MAX_LEN);
    snprintf(buffer, MAX_LEN, "%s", this->body.c_str()); // Body:
    string line5(buffer);

    this->email_contents.push_back(line5); // body
    this->email_contents.push_back(endLine); // \r\n
    this->email_contents.push_back(boundary); // boundary

    // add in the attachments
    for (i = 0; i < attachments.size(); i++) {
        this->email_contents.push_back(this->attachments[i]);
    }

    // add the last boundary with the two hyphens
    string lastBoundary(email_template[END_OF_TRANSMISSION_BOUNDARY]);
    this->email_contents.push_back(lastBoundary);

    // specify that we don't want to send any more data
    string endTransmission(email_template[END_OF_TRANSMISSION]);
    this->email_contents.push_back(endTransmission);
}

/*
    This function was taken and modified from:
    https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-ssl.html
*/
int Email::send(void) const
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    struct curl_slist* recipients = NULL;
    struct upload_status upload_ctx;

    upload_ctx.lines_read = 0;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    global_vec = this->email_contents;

    if (curl) {
        /* Set username and password */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, this->smtp_user.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, this->smtp_password.c_str());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // allows emails to be sent 

                                                           /* This is the URL for your mailserver. Note the use of smtps:// rather
                                                           * than smtp:// to request a SSL based connection. */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, this->smtp_host.c_str());

        /* If you want to connect to a site who isn't using a certificate that is
        * signed by one of the certs in the CA bundle you have, you can skip the
        * verification of the server's certificate. This makes the connection
        * A LOT LESS SECURE.
        *
        * If you have a CA cert for the server stored someplace else than in the
        * default bundle, then the CURLOPT_CAPATH option might come handy for
        * you. */
#ifdef SKIP_PEER_VERIFICATION
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
#endif

        /* If the site you're connecting to uses a different host name that what
        * they have mentioned in their server certificate's commonName (or
        * subjectAltName) fields, libcurl will refuse to connect. You can skip
        * this check, but this will make the connection less secure. */
#ifdef SKIP_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
#endif

        /* Note that this option isn't strictly required, omitting it will result
        * in libcurl sending the MAIL FROM command with empty sender data. All
        * autoresponses should have an empty reverse-path, and should be directed
        * to the address in the reverse-path which triggered them. Otherwise,
        * they could cause an endless loop. See RFC 5321 Section 4.5.5 for more
        * details.
        */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, this->from.c_str());

        /* Add two recipients, in this particular case they correspond to the
        * To: and Cc: addressees in the header, but they could be any kind of
        * recipient. */
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, this->to.c_str());
        if (this->cc.length() > 0) {
            recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, this->cc.c_str());
        }

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);

        /* We're using a callback function to specify the payload (the headers and
        * body of the message). You could just use the CURLOPT_READDATA option to
        * specify a FILE pointer to read from. */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

        /* Since the traffic will be encrypted, it is very useful to turn on debug
        * information within libcurl to see what is happening during the
        * transfer */
        // curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        /* Send the message */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* Free the list of recipients */
        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);

        /* Always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return (int)res;
}

void Email::removeAllAttachments()
{
    this->attachments.clear();
}

void Email::clearEmailContents()
{
    this->email_contents.clear();
    this->attachments.clear();
}

void Email::dump(void) const
{
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Email contents: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < this->email_contents.size(); i++) {
        cout << this->email_contents[i];
        if (i == 20) {
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\nEmail attachments: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < this->attachments.size(); i++) {
        cout << this->attachments[i];
        if (i == 5) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void base64_encode(char* input_buf, char* output_buf, size_t input_size)
{
    char in[3];
    char out[4];
    size_t len = input_size;

    *output_buf = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; )
    {
        int buf3_len = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            in[j] = input_buf[i++];
            if (i > len)
                in[j] = 0;
            else
                buf3_len++;
        }
        if (len > 0)
        {
            encodeblock(in, out, buf3_len);
            strncat(output_buf, out, 4);
        }
    }
}

void encodeblock(char* in, char* out, int len)
{
    out[0] = (char)b64_table[(int)(in[0] >> 2)];
    out[1] = (char)b64_table[(int)(((in[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((in[1] & 0xf0) >> 4))];
    out[2] = (char)(len > 1 ? b64_table[(int)(((in[1] & 0x0f) << 2) | ((in[2] & 0xc0) >> 6))] : '=');
    out[3] = (char)(len > 2 ? b64_table[(int)(in[2] & 0x3f)] : '=');
}

static size_t payload_source(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    struct upload_status* upload_ctx = (struct upload_status*)userp;
    const char* data;

    if ((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size * nmemb) < 1)) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (upload_ctx->lines_read >= 0 && upload_ctx->lines_read < global_vec.size())
    {
        data = global_vec[upload_ctx->lines_read].c_str();

        if (data) {
            size_t len = strlen(data);
            memcpy(ptr, data, len);
            upload_ctx->lines_read++;

            return len;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "email.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    Email e;
    int curlError = 0;
    // e.dump();

    e.setTo("receiver@example.com");
    e.setFrom("sender@example.com");
    e.setSubject("Test Email");
    e.setCc("");
    e.setBody("Do not reply to this email");

    e.setSMTP_host("smtp://smtp.mail.com:587");
    e.setSMTP_username("sender@example.com");
    e.setSMTP_password("sender_password");

    e.addAttachment("");
    // e.addAttachment("email.h");
    // e.addAttachment("main.cpp");

    e.constructEmail();
    e.dump();

    curlError = e.send();

    if (curlError) {
        cout << "Error sending email!" << endl;
    }

    else {
        cout << "Email sent successfully!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What is the reason this same code runs perfectly on one project but doesn't work on another?

**EDIT:**

error happens in **Email::send(void)** on the line :

```
    global_vec2 = this->email_contents;
```

but I cannot try/catch it. it doesn't throws exception.

**EDIT2 :**

Problem is caused by static vector. It doesn't exist, doesn't initialize. I don't understand what's causing this project to prevent static std::vectors from being created.

Comment: Almost certainly the reason is a bug in the code. Code with bugs doesn't have to fail, it's perfectly common for bugged code to work in one situation but them fail in another.

Comment: That code compiles and seems to run fine resulting in the expected result, does not mean that it's is valid. It still can have an error resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: Too much code! [mcve] please

Comment: @t.niese forgot to say it fails only on release mode. edited that detail. it works fine on both debug and release for first project. but works on debug and fails on release for second project.

Comment: As I said, you have an error somewhere in your code resulting in undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means that your program gets into a state in which anything could happen, from seemingly working, to wrong results, or crashing. And which one of those will happen can differ depending on where you run it, what kind of optimizations settings you use, or even from which directory you launch it on the same pc.

Comment: Hello. Beware that in visual studio debuger, If you want to break on all possible exception you have to explicitly select them. By default not all of them are enabled.

Comment: Not only it's certain that there is a bug in the code, but also, in my experience, if your debugger complains about something in the internals of the standard library, then your code is writing to the memory location where it is not supposed to write.